# Customizing ExtJS CSS - some difficulties

Tags: css, extjs, extjs4, customization

Before beginning, I know how to customize the ExtJS css with cls but I had some difficulties on some points

Here's my code :

```
            {
            region: 'south',
            height: 70,
            layout: 
                {
                type: 'hbox',
                align: 'center',
                pack: 'center',
                xtype: 'container',
                cls: 'testbackground',
                },
            border: false,
            items: [
                {
                xtype: 'button',
                cls: 'testbackground',
                scale: 'large',
                width: 200,
                text: "Consulter",
                margins: '15 5 5 5',
                },
                {
                xtype: 'button',
                scale: 'large',
                text: "Télécharger",
                width: 200,
                margins: '15 5 5 5',
                },
                ]
                },
```

And he'es my css

```
.testbackground
{
    background: red;
}
```

When I test, the background button is red, it's ok. But not the region's one.
What I would like is to change the background color of the container, not only the button.
I can't make it work. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the config for `xtype` and `cls` inside the `layout` config, which is not valid. Move them to the root of your **south region** config, and it will work.

Here's a live example: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/269

And some working code:

```
Ext.application({
    name : 'Fiddle',

    launch : function() {
        Ext.create('Ext.container.Container', {
            height: 500,
            width: 500,
            layout: 'border',
            items: [
                {
                    region: 'center',
                    html: 'I am center'
                },
                {
                    region: 'south',
                    height: 70,
                    xtype: 'container',
                    cls: 'test',
                    layout: {
                        type: 'hbox',
                        align: 'center',
                        pack: 'center'
                    },
                    border: false,
                    items: [
                        {
                        xtype: 'button',
                        cls: 'testbackground',
                        scale: 'large',
                        width: 200,
                        text: "Consulter",
                        margins: '15 5 5 5',
                        },
                        {
                        xtype: 'button',
                        scale: 'large',
                        text: "Télécharger",
                        width: 200,
                        margins: '15 5 5 5',
                        },
                    ]
                }
            ],
            renderTo: Ext.getBody()
        })
    }
});
```